# TabLayout hide/show animation

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-tablayout

I have `Toolbar` with `TabLayout` which I'd like to hide/show at some points, I'd like to animate the hide/show process of the tabs (The toolbar remains visible)... putting a scale animation on the `TabLayout` hides it but the height of the toolbar remains the same, as if the tabs are there... any suggestions ?

```
 public void showTabs(boolean show) {
        if (show) {
          //tabLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tabLayout.animate().scaleY(1).setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator()).start();

        } else {
            tabLayout.animate().scaleY(0).setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator()).start();
            //tabLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` to your `AppBarLayout` and in your JAVA just use `tablLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` and `tablLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE)` for visibility and enjoy the result!

Comment: Excellent, thanks! Is it possible to set the speed of the animation?

Comment: nm, AppBarLayout.getAnimation().setDuration() probably works :)